# How can I customize my bootloader to make it prettier?

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I hate how when I turn on the computer it just (after the hp logo, which I hate having also), shows white text on a black background. I'm wondering if there's easy ways to customize this (I'm choosing between Windows 7 and two separate Ubuntu 10.10 installs). I've read a little about some complicated ways to do this, but is there not some simpler ways by installing a package on ubuntu or something? I don't want to hack a bunch of code together to get a simple effect.

I'm hoping for actual images and having like the windows 7 logo and ubuntu logo to choose from.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Yes... there's BURG.  With it you can easily give your bootloader a theme.  Beware though that if you do something stupid, you could break it and lock yourself out for a while.

Look at the following link for instructions (really pretty simple, mostly GUI)
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/burg-manager-10-released-with-option-to.html

You'll see an example image. Scroll down to where it says:
"For a complete how-to on using Burg Manager, see our Install And Configure Burg In Ubuntu With Burg Manager post."  Click on that link, then do what it says.

BURG might add 0.5s to your boot time, but looking at the result, who cares?
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [BURG](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Burg). It's got some themes, but there's more out there.

Here's an example:

[image: Radiance text]

Answer (score 1):

**Daniel Richter** has developed a **GUI configuration tool** to allow users to change the **Grub 2** settings without using the command line. The application allows the user to add, remove, freeze, rename and reorder boot menu items. It will also allow changes to the Grub 2 configuration settings such as background image and menu timeout.

you can use it and install it follow this [GUIDE](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10340183#post10340183)

if you want in GRUB 2 you can read this [GUIDE](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275) too

so thx to *DANIEL*

Answer (score 0):

You can also install 5 themes with just 3 simple commands
(Credit goes to [Chris titus blog](https://christitus.com/bootloader-themes/)).

```
git clone https://github.com/ChrisTitusTech/Top-5-Bootloader-Themes
cd Top-5-Bootloader-Themes
sudo ./install.sh
```

Thanks to **Chris titus** for this amazing work.